# Why must a particular bijective linear operator on an $n$ - dimensional vector space satisfy a polynomial equation? (Without Cayley-Hamilton theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve the problem in the screenshot below. I solved the first one, noting that because the basis contains $f$-images of some points, so any element can be expressed as the $f$-image of some other point, making $f$ surjective, and next, observing that $E$ is $n$ -dimensional, $f:E\to E$ is injective by rank-nullity and hence bijective. So far so good, but I'm having trouble in proving problem no. 2. My initial thoughts were that:

$\{Id(x_0), f(x_0), f^2(x_0)\dots f^n(x_0)\}$ are linearly dependent, so there must exist a linear combination $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\lambda_jf^j(x_0)=0.$ But this doesn't necessarily imply that $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\lambda_jf^j\equiv 0.$ Any hints or solutions please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since $\lbrace f(x_0), f^2(x_0), ..., f^n(x_0) \rbrace$ is a basis of $E$, then $\mathcal{B}'=\lbrace x_0, f(x_0), ..., f^{n-1}(x_0) \rbrace$ is also a basis of $E$.

The vector $f^n(x_0)$ can be decomposed in this basis $\mathcal{B}'$ : there exists some scalar $a_0$, $a_1$,..., $a_{n-1} \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $f^n(x_0)= - a_0 x_0 - ... - a_{n-1} f^{n-1}(x_0)$, i.e. such that $$f^n(x_0)+ a_0 x_0 + ... + a_{n-1} f^{n-1}(x_0)=0$$

Let $g = - \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k f^k$. By definition, one has already $g(x_0)=f^n(x_0)$.

Moreover, for every $i \in \lbrace 0, ..., n-1 \rbrace$, one has
\begin{align*} g(f^i(x_0)) = - \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k f^k(f^i(x_0)) &= f^i\left[- \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k f^k(x_0)\right] \\ &= f^i(g(x_0))= f^i(f^n(x_0))=f^n(f^i(x_0))
\end{align*}

So the two linear maps $f^n$ and $g$ are equal on every elements of the basis $\mathcal{B}'$, so they are equal everywhere. One has $f^n=g$, i.e.
$$\boxed{f^n +a_0 \mathrm{Id}_E + a_1 f + ... + a_{n-1}f^{n-1}=0}$$

Comment: Thank you! So the main points used are: i) bases correspond to bases under bijective linear maps and ii) if two linear maps are equal on a basis, they're equal everywhere on the vector space - thanks again!

Comment: @LearningMath In fact, point $(i)$ is unnecessary : if $\lbrace f(a_1), ..., f(a_n) \rbrace$ is a basis, then $\lbrace a_1, ..., a_n \rbrace$ is quite easily a basis too (without reusing the fact that $f$ is bijective). The key-point is point $(ii)$, indeed !

Comment: Thanks, but actually assuming that  $\{f(a_1),...,f(a_n)\}$ is a basis implies that $f$ is surjective and hence injective by rank-nullity for the special case where domain = codomain. Perhaps also relevant that this is no longer true if $f:V\to W, \infty>dim(V) >dim(W)>0.$ So we're using the fact that $f$ is bijective in proving the statement in your last comment. For independence part, there's no problem though, as for that we don't need $f$ to be anything special and domain may not equal codomain.

Comment: But for linear span part, the proof doesn't seem to go through, as for $w\in V,$ we have $f(w)=f(\lambda_1v_1+\dots\lambda_nv_n), $ but this in general just gives us that $w-(\lambda_1v_1+\dots\lambda_nv_n)\in ker(f),$ but if we don't know the kernel is zero, we can't progress further. And to have kernel zero, we need injectivity, that follows from surjectivity of $f$, but then essentially we're using that $f$ is biective, in disguise...